# Are knot complements prime 3-manifolds?

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology, knot-theory, solid-geometry

Well, that is basically the question. Is the complement of a knot, i.e. an smoothly embedded copy of $S^1$ in $S^3$ a prime $3$-manifold?

Here I mean by prime:

A connected $3$-manifold $M$ is *prime* if there is no decomposition as a connected sum $N_1\# N_2$ of two manifolds neither of which is the $3$-sphere $S^3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Alexander's Lemma, knot complements are irreducible $3$-manifolds, hence also prime manifolds, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_manifold).

Comment: I accepted the answer but noted that at least a short search did not lead to a result to what "Alexander`s Lemma" is. The one with compact iff has a subbasis... etc? Found it now.

Comment: Thank you. You still need a link ? [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegaard_splitting) is one.